# Javascript how can bind var

Tags: javascript, object, var

```
var Global = {
    alpha : 1,
    color : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, '+this.alpha+')'
}
console.log(Global.color);
```

this code is something wrong.
In this code, How can i use var alpha in Global.color.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Global.alpha`? Global is a horrible variable name - whose global is it and js is nitpicked for the global scope to begin with.

`this.alpha` is looking at the current context (which is not going to be Global) and access **It's** alpha.

```
var Global = {
    alpha : 1,
    getColor : function ()
    {
        return 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + this.alpha + ')';
    }
};

console.log(Global.getColor());
```

Comment: It's fine, and because of the `var` keyword it's a local variable. Probably in some canvas-related code.

Comment: @Bergi If this was only in a script tag wouldn't Global be appended to the global scope?

Comment: Of course it would, but it hardly is. The surrounding scope is irrelevant to the question, so it was omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:

```
var Global = { alpha: 1 };
Global.color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + Global.alpha + ')';
console.log(Global.color);
```